# Checking div visibility using js

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I have two divs (soru and yanit) in a div (alan). 
When someone clicks on the screen, the other invisible div must be visible. At the begining, "yanit" div is invisible and "soru" div is visible.

My code is below but doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
<script>
window.onload= function(){

var divSoru = document.getElementById("soru");
var divYanit = document.getElementById("yanit");
document.getElementById("alan").addEventListener('click', containerClick, false);

function containerClick(){
if(divSoru.style.visibility=='visible'){
    divSoru.style.visibility=='hidden';
    divYanit.style.visibility='visible';
}
if(divSoru.style.visibility=='hidden'){
    divYanit.style.visibility='hidden';
    divSoru.style.visibility=='visible';
         }
     }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: `element.style` only checks for inline style. Maybe you can use `class` instead, or assign `soru` an initial inline visibility.

Comment: You've got two "=" signs for divSoru. Should be divSoru.style.visibility='hidden'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made 2 mistake:

```
if(divSoru.style.visibility=='visible'){
    divSoru.style.visibility='hidden'; // you used == 
    divYanit.style.visibility='visible';
}
if(divSoru.style.visibility=='hidden'){
    divYanit.style.visibility='hidden';
    divSoru.style.visibility='visible'; // you used == 
}
```

Now it should work.